# How to check if a filesystem supports hard links in linux?

Tags: c#, linux, filesystems, pathconf

What's going on here is I have a construct that goes something like this:

```
    if (link(source, intermediate))
    {
        if (pathconf(dirname(source), _PC_LINK_MAX) == 1)
        {
            /* do atomic algorithm that only works if the filesystem does not support hard links */
        }
        else
        {
            var errno = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            var ci = new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
            throw new IOException(ci.Message, errno);
        }
    } else {
        /* continue atomic algorithm that only works if the filesystem supports hard links */
    }
```

`pathconf(mountpoint, _PC_LINK_MAX);` returns 127 on a FAT filesystem. You gotta be kidding me.

So I've got to find another way to check if links are definitely not supported on the target filesystem. Locking onto `EPERM` is inadequate.

Yes, this question has always been in C# with P/Invokes for libc functions. Yes, I've had to write them down as I needed them.